# Fade In don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have wrote this javascript to show some images with id: imgFotogramma1/imgFotogramma2/ecc.. randomly in 8 different div with id Fotogramma1/Fotogramma2/ecc..:

```
function rullino() {
    var immagini = new Array("strutture/1.jpg", "strutture/2.jpg", "strutture/3.jpg", "strutture/4.jpg", "strutture/5.jpg", "strutture/6.jpg", "strutture/7.jpg", "strutture/8.jpg", "strutture/9.jpg");
    for (i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
        var x = Math.floor(immagini.length * Math.random(1));
        var imgId = "imgFotogramma" + i;
        $(function () {
            $(imgId).fadeIn(1000);
            src = $(imgId).attr('src');
            src = immagini[x];
            alert(src);
        });
    }
    setInterval("rullino()", 4000);
};
```

Now,this code start when body is loaded and its repeated every 4 seconds but i don't understand why the images are not displayed. I have started to work with Jquery not too much time ago and probably something are wrong.

I want to specify that: if i use normally javascript to assign to the src attribute the value of immagini[x],all work fine and the images are displayed.I have problem only to apply the fadein() motion.

I need a help to understand where is wrong,i have studied the fadeIn() API and i have tried to apply to my case.

Thanks in advance to anyone want to help me.

Comment: `var imgId = "#imgFotogramma"+i;`. Also, what's the point of `src = $(imgId).attr('src');`, if you're re-assigning it in the very next line?

Comment: Right,is wrong,i have removed the src = immagini[x] line and i have replace with $(imgId).attr('src', immagini[x]);

Now the images are displayed but the fadeIn don't work.

I have to assign the fadeIn() to the <img> or <div>? I think i have to assign the fadein to the obj i want to display,right?

Comment: Your images are already visible. You must hide them first, so they can _fade in_. You could do `$(imgId).hide().fadeIn(1000);`

Comment: Yeah,i have tried 2 second first you have posted.

Thanks a lot john,today i have learned some about fadein and jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select an ID, use `# + elemID`. Like this:

```
var imgId = "#imgFotogramma" + i;
```

Also, fade will not occur if the element is not hidden. First hide it, and then fade it in:

```
$(imgId).hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(imgId).fadeIn(1000);
```

should be:

```
$('#'+imgId).fadeIn(1000);
```

Use `# + idOfElemnt` to select element with particular id.

Answer (score 1):

You already doing it right. Just replace

```
  var imgId = "imgFotogramma"+i;
```

With

```
 var imgId = "#imgFotogramma"+i;
```

Since your are using the ID of the image, then your must have to use the "#" for id for applying the jQuery on it.